# parsing JSON from splunk fetching from s3

Tags: json, amazon-s3, blob, splunk

When i fetch JSON file from azure block storage and aws S3 and parse it in splunk it parses it as normal file.

instead if i try to upload JSON file directly in slunk portal then it parse JSON properly and displays results.

how to parse it as JSON and display when its automatically fetched from S3 or Blop storage

i have tried using following [link](https://splunkonbigdata.com/2020/02/18/aws-s3-and-splunk-integration/).

i could be able to parse as normal log file but not as JSON

Comment: What does your `props.conf` look like for this ingest?

Comment: `DATETIME_CONFIG = 
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = json
KV_MODE = none
LINE_BREAKER = ([\r\n]+)
NO_BINARY_CHECK = true
category = Structured
description = JavaScript Object Notation format. For more information, visit http://json.org/
disabled = false
pulldown_type = 1`

Comment: would you put that - *formatted* - into your question, please? It's nigh-unreadable as a comment :)